# Mysql multiple conditions on same column

Tags: mysql, sql

My table categories_article looks like this :

[image: My table categories_article looks like this]

I want to return all articles which have categorie 1 and 11 and 13 and 22.
I am trying to do it like this :

```
select * from categories_article where categorie in(1,11,13,22)
```

But the request return article 13, and in this example the article 13  doesn't have categorie 22.

Please somebody help me thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want with a `group by` and `having` clause:

```
select article
from categories_article
where categorie in (1, 11, 13, 22)
group by article
having count(*) = 4;
```

If you can have duplicates in the table, use `count(distinct categorie) = 4`.

Comment: great work, but when I implement it with strings I get a blank result. Could be that the query need to be different?

Comment: @fallcoshkoder . . . This should work fine with strings.  Perhaps you should ask a *new* question about your data and specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use an `EXISTS` statement to make sure that each of those categories are found for the articles.  There's bound to be a better way to do this, but here's a solution:

```
Select  *
From    categories_article  A
Where   Exists 
(
    Select  *
    From    categories_article  B
    Where   A.article = B.article
    And     B.categorie = 1
)
And     Exists 
(
    Select  *
    From    categories_article  B
    Where   A.article = B.article
    And     B.categorie = 11
)
And     Exists 
(
    Select  *
    From    categories_article  B
    Where   A.article = B.article
    And     B.categorie = 13
)
And     Exists 
(
    Select  *
    From    categories_article  B
    Where   A.article = B.article
    And     B.categorie = 22
)
```